# How can I use Map function for an Array with values and another array as a value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to Display some values of a course. How can I use the map function for this data which is an Array with name and another Array.

I tried to use Map function on map function which creates one new array but I can not add the name of the course only the name of the parts

Expected :

```
Half Stack application development

Fundamentals of React  10
Using props to pass data 7 
State of Component 14 
Redux 11 

Node.js
Routing 3 
Middlewares 7
```

Actual:

```
Fundamentals of React  10
Using props to pass data 7 
State of Component 14 
Redux 11 
Routing 3 
Middlewares 7
```

It is missing the Course name and some separation for the courses

```
const App = () => {
const courses = [
 {
   name: "Half Stack application development",
   id: 1,
   parts: [
     {
       name: "Fundamentals of React",
       exercises: 10,
       id: 1
     },
     {
       name: "Using props to pass data",
       exercises: 7,
       id: 2
     },
     {
       name: "State of a component",
       exercises: 14,
       id: 3
     },
     {
       name: "Redux",
       exercises: 11,
       id: 4
     }
   ]
  },
  {
   name: "Node.js",
   id: 2,
   parts: [
     {
       name: "Routing",
       exercises: 3,
       id: 1
     },
     {
       name: "Middlewares",
       exercises: 7,
       id: 2
     }
    ]
  }
  ];
 const rows = () =>
 courses.map(note => note.parts.map(b => <Course key={b.id} course={b} 
/>));

const Course = ({ course }) => {
return (
   <p>
      {" "}
     {course.name} {course.exercises}
   </p>
  );
 };
```

Comment: I don't see any code to deal with `note` other than to get the `parts`. You would need to add code for that. You also seem to be missing a `}` for `App` and the evaluation of `rows`

Answer (score 0):

You aren't returning anything from your App component.

you need to return the result of your map call.

Also this:

```
const rows = () =>
 courses.map(note => note.parts.map(b => <Course key={b.id} course={b} 
/>));
```

Is creating an array of arrays and it is removing the name of courses.  You need to map over it like this if you want to keep that data:

```
const rows = () =>
  courses.map(note => {
     return {
       ...note,
       parts: note.parts.map(b => <Course key={b.id} course={b} />)
     }
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
courses.map(note => note.parts.map(b => <Course key={b.id} course={b} />));
```

The above `map` is using `note.parts`. So its already missed out the name property. Workaround is map and pass complete course to the `Course` component.

```
courses.map(note => note.map(b => <Course key={b.id} course={b} />));

const Course = ({ course }) => {
return (
   <div>
   <p>
      {" "}
     {course.name} 
   </p>
   <p> {course.parts.map(x=> (<div>{x.name} {x.execises}</div>)}</p>
   </div>
  );
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just flatten the array with all courses using reduce and map over the result normally like this -

```
const allCourses = courses.reduce( (agg,course)=>{
    return [...agg, course,...course.parts]
},[])

const rows = allCourses.map( course => <Course key={course.id} course={course} /> )
```

Hope this helps!